# Conducting a slow scan television net via an FM repeater

Tags: procedure, repeater, net, sstv

I've heard the Houston AMSAT Net sends slow scan television pictures as part of its regular proceeding.  Is this unique to them or are there other examples out there?

Answer (score 1):

Appleton WI http://www.apleinc.com/WB9KMW/SSTV_2M.html

Columbus OH http://www.qsl.net/n/n8tut//sstv/

Kokomo IN http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGVMJu_1MpI

Sacramento CA http://www.n6na.org/nets/sstv-net

And, a 2005 list, some of which are sure to be active still http://www.hffax.de/html/net.htm